# Verifying checksum for files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, checksum, webhdfs

I'm using webhdfs to ingest data from Local file system to HDFS. Now I want to ensure integrity of files ingested into HDFS.

How can I make sure transferred files are not corrrupted/altered etc?

I used below webhdfs command to get the checksum of file

```
curl -i -L --negotiate -u: -X GET "http://$hostname:$port/webhdfs/v1/user/path?op=GETFILECHECKSUM"
```

How should I use above checksum to ensure the integrity of Ingested files? please suggest

Below is the steps I'm following

```
>md5sum locale_file
740c461879b484f4f5960aa4f67a145b

 >hadoop fs -checksum locale_file
locale_file     MD5-of-0MD5-of-512CRC32C        000002000000000000000000f4ec0c298cd6196ffdd8148ae536c9fe
```

Checksum of file on local system is different than same file on HDFS I need to compare checksum how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do that will be to calculate the checksum locally and than match it against the hadoop checksum after you ingest it.

I wrote a library to calculate check sum locally for it, in case any body is interested.
https://github.com/srch07/HDFSChecksumForLocalfile

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
curl -i "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=GETFILECHECKSUM"
```

Refer follow link for full information

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Get_File_Checksum

Comment: can you please explain ? I did not understand what exactly this command is doing

Answer (score 1):

It can be done from the console like below

```
$ md5sum locale_file
740c461879b484f4f5960aa4f67a145b

$ hadoop fs -cat locale_file |md5sum -
740c461879b484f4f5960aa4f67a145b -
```

You can also verify local file via code

```
import java.io._
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

val md5sum = DigestUtils.md5Hex("locale_file")
```

and for the Hadoop

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.io._

val md5sum = MD5Hash.digest(FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration).open(new Path("locale_file"))).toString
```